# Исправьте код в Python

Tags: python

Учителю захотелось узнать, кто из учеников присутствовал на всех уроках с начала учебного года. Для каждого урока у учителя есть листок со списком присутствовавших учеников. Фамилии в списках не обязательно идут в алфавитном порядке. Определите фамилии учеников, которые присутствовали на всех уроках.

**Формат ввода**
В первой строчке указано число листков M. Далее идёт M блоков строчек, описывающих листки с фамилиями. На первой строчке каждого блока указано количество фамилий Ni, затем идёт Ni строчек с фамилиями тех, кто был на уроке i.

**Формат вывода**
Фамилии учеников, бывших на всех уроках, в произвольном порядке. Каждая фамилия должна быть записана на отдельной строке. Гарантируется, что хотя бы один ученик был на всех уроках.

```
n = int(input())
lst = set()
sep = set()
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(int(input())):
    a = input()
    if a in lst:
      sep.add(a)
    lst.add(a)
res = lst.intersection(sep)
print(*sorted(res), sep='\n')
```

не проходит один тест, когда вводятся M = 3 листкам(см скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что означает "не работает вывод"?

Comment: @Эникейщик выдает пустую строку

Comment: ну значит в res ничего нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик и как это исправить?

Comment: @Эникейщик более улучшил свой код , но один тест не проходит(см всё в вопросе)

Comment: ваш код выводит сейчас учеников, которые были минимум на двух уроках (если я не запутался). intersection() надо бы делать после каждого урока, чтобы удалить тех, кого на одном из уроков не было.

Comment: @Эникейщик попробовал , не сработало

Comment: @Эникейщик также помимо этого, попробовал поставить intersection() и на другие позиции, результат разный выводит, но не приближенный к нужному

Comment: Значит неправильно пробовал.

Comment: @Эникейщик попробовал уже по-разному, даже добавляя еще один intersection() и все равно результат тот же

Comment: Вообще, вы, наверное, можете сделать и попроще: просто создайте массив множеств, наполните каждое множество учениками из соответствующего листка, а после этого можно просто пересечь все множества в массиве.

Comment: @EzikBro спасибо, вы меня натолкнули на еще БОЛЕЕ легкую идею по решению

Comment: @Эникейщик пользователь EzikBro натолкнул на идею очень хорошую использовать словарь, сразу в его создании из списка sep, и чтобы в value= введенному слову, а key = сколько раз это слово было и в конце просто  пробежать по словарю и если key == введеному числу уроков , то мы выводим elem(который равен value)

Comment: Если это для вас более легко, то ок.

Comment: @марат, Уберите своё "верное решение" из вопроса и добавьте его в ответ ниже

Comment: @vp_arth исправлено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
n = int(input())
sep = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(int(input())):
        a = input()
        sep.append(a) 
dict1 = dict(Counter(sep))
for elem in dict1:
    if dict1.get(elem) == n:
        print(elem)
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, в чем была суть проблемы

Comment: @Niki-Timofe в вопросе?